# Isotropy irreducible forms of a manifold

Tags: representation-theory, riemannian-geometry

Let $ M $ be a compact connected manifold. Suppose that
$$
M=G_1/K_1
$$
is isotropy irreducible
and
$$
M=G_2/K_2
$$
is also isotropy irreducible. Here $ G_1,G_2 $ are compact connected Lie groups and $ K_1,K_2 $ are subgroups. Must it be the case that $ G_1=G_2 $ or is it possible to have two different isotropy irreducible forms of a smooth manifold $ M $ in this sense?

For example, $ S^5=SO_6/SO_5 $ is isotropy irreducible, but $ S^5=SU_3/SU_2 $ is not isotropy irreducible. And I would imagine that the round $ S^5=SO_6/SO_5 $ is the only isotropy irreducible "form" of $ S^5 $ in this sense.

Comment: what does it means isotropy irreducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to have different forms.

An example of this form is the natural metric on
$$
S^6 \cong G_2/SU_3
$$
versus the round metric on
$$
S^6 \cong SO_7/SO_6
$$
these are both isotropy irreducible. Note that compact $ G_2 $ is contained in $ SO_7 $ as the subgroup of automorphisms of an octonion algebra and moreover this is the minimal irrep of $ G_2 $. Also $ G_2\cap SO_6=SU_3 $ as subgroups of $ SO_7 $. Here we mean the natural $ SU_3 $ subgroup of $ SO_6(\mathbb{R}) $.